# Vimeo Private isn't playable in Ionic 3 Angular 4 application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, vimeo-api

I want to display private videos in Ionic 3 app, only public videos are playable and not the Private videos.
The main idea is :- I want to give access to video on specific URL i.e. The video aren't accessible outside the website.

When is embed using iframe or just use it with div, private video isn't playable, instead error is displayed such as -

> Sorry, Because of its privacy settings, this video cannot be played
>   here.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTGoL.png)

I have provide my snippets as below -

```
import Player from "@vimeo/player";
... other imports ...

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-videoplayer',
  templateUrl: 'videoplayer.html',
})

export class VideoplayerPage {
  @ViewChild('player_container') playerContainer;
  private player: Player;
  id:any;
  idnew:any;
  name:any;
  envMobile_Token:any;
  envAuth_token:any;
  url:any;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public platform: Platform,
    public Ajax :AjaxProvider,
    public forgotCtrl: AlertController,
    public loadingProvider:LoadingProvider,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.id = navParams.get('id');
        let ckurl = navParams.get('url');
        if(ckurl){
        //  this.getSafeUrl('https://player.vimeo.com/video/223394199');
        }
        this.userdata()
      })
  }
  userdata(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('user')){
      this.userdata  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).user_id;
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('Mobile_Token')){
      this.envMobile_Token  = localStorage.getItem('Mobile_Token');
    }
    if(localStorage.getItem('Auth_Token')){
      this.envAuth_token = localStorage.getItem('Auth_Token');
    }
  }
  getSafeUrl(url) {
    this.url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    //this.url = url;
    console.log(this.url)       
    }
  ionViewDidLoad() {

      this.player = new Player(this.playerContainer.nativeElement, {
      id: 223394199,
    });
  }

}
```

> Error Message:- Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   “https://vimeo.com/223394199” is not embeddable. Error:
>   “https://vimeo.com/223394199” is not embeddable.

I have tried with many stackoverflow & adobe forum suggestions and they say that u have to do somewhat like [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2461367)

I expected the video to be Playable, but displaying error as the above error image.

Comment: What is the video's embed privacy set to? If it's set to "embed nowhere", obviously it cannot be embedded. If it's set to "domain privacy" then it cannot be embedded within an app, since the player isn't embedded on a website with a domain.

Comment: "i have to make video accessible only via domain URL, and the video must not be accessible other than domain URL", So is there other way around that i can do this

Comment: Im facing the same problem also how to adjust the video player as responsive player. It get a centain width in pixel..

Comment: Did anyone find the soluation?